# Automate Firefox on Android device

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, ui-automation

I want to invoke firefox browser in Android device, i wrote following code but it is invoking my desktop browser. Instead I want to open mobile firefox browser.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.SetPreference("platformName", "android");
options.SetPreference("deviceName", "LG8IA0GE822I8G6A");
options.SetPreference(CapabilityType.Version, "7.0");
options.SetPreference("androidPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
IWebDriver driverOne = new FirefoxDriver(@"Path to gecko Driver", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Hi, no solution?